# listbox selected text with listbox text + custom text (richtextbox)

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I'm making an application for this website: http://incil.info
What I'm trying to make is when a listbox text is selected, it will show it on the richTextBox with the selected text from listbox + custom text.

I'm a bit stuck here..

For now, here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Kutsal_Kitap
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }

        private void btnAra_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();


        }
    }
    }
```

This code will only show the selected text from listbox to richtextbox.
How do I also add custom text below?

Comment: do you mean this? richTextBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()+"custom text";

Comment: Hahah I forgot about + " "; Yes exactly what I mean, but I want to add custom text for every selected text from list box, so not the same text appears on every selected listbox text.

Comment: what's the custom text?

Comment: I want to add different text when a selection is selected from a listbox. I want to add text specifying to the selected listbox text.

Comment: Like this picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p8748fpn07o3g05/form.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add custom text by conditions

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
var str =listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
if(str=="aaa")
{
        richTextBox1.Text = str + "custom text 1";
}
else if(str=="bbb")
{
        richTextBox1.Text = str + "custom text 2";
}
...


    }
```

Comment: I also have a search textbox and search button. I want this to highlight for searched text in richtextbox.